# Javascript: Detect if a string is trimmed

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to come up with a Regexp that detects whether a string in Javascript is trimmed or not. That means, it doesn't have whitespace at the beginning or end.

So far I have

```
^[^\s].*[^\s]$
```

This works if the string is long, but for short strings such as `a`, it will not work because the pattern wants a non-space, any character, then another non-space. That `a` is trimmed, but doesn't follow the pattern.

Help me find the correct regex.

Comment: why regex ? IMO `str.trim()===str` is more readable

Comment: I'm not using imperative programming here. That's why I need to declare a regex. More precisely, I'm using this regex in validate.js, a library where you specify validators and stuff. So the line you said wouldn't be of use here.

Comment: ok fair enough...

Answer (score 1):

Try this to make a second char optional:

```
^[^\s](.*[^\s])?$
```

Comment: As expected from the incredibly amazing Marc Anton. This works.

Comment: `regex.test('a')
true
regex.test(' a')
true
regex.test(' a ')`
true` this doesn't work properly! It shows true even though there is a space in the beginning or end.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to take your existing regex (`^[^\s].*[^\s]$`) and add a separate part to it specifically to test for a single non-space character (`^[^\s]$`), combining the two parts with `|`:

```
/(^[^\s]$)|(^[^\s].*[^\s]$)/
```

But I find sometimes it is simpler to test for the opposite case and then invert the result with `!`. So in your case, have the regex test for a space at the beginning or end:

```
!/(^\s)|(\s$)/.test(someString)
```

Encapsulated in a function:

```js
function isTrimmed(s) {
  return !/(^\s)|(\s$)/.test(s)
}

console.log(isTrimmed("  a  ")) // false
console.log(isTrimmed("a  "))   // false
console.log(isTrimmed("  a"))   // false
console.log(isTrimmed("a"))     // true
console.log(isTrimmed("abc"))   // true
console.log(isTrimmed("a b c")) // true
console.log(isTrimmed(""))      // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regex :

```
^([\s]+[\w]*)?([\w]*[\s]+)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the nicest answer but [Negative lookahead](http://www.regextester.com/jssyntax.html) should work:

```
/^(?!(?:.*\s$)|(?:^\s.*)).*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

[`(?=^\S)[\W\w]*\S$`](https://regex101.com/r/JLusHR/1)

- `(?=^\S)` Lookahead for non-space character at the start of the string (matches without consuming the string; will start match from first character again)
- `[\W\w]*` Match any number of characters
- `\S$` Match non-space character at the end of the string

So for `a`:

- `(?=^\S)` Matches `a` at the start of the string (resets current position to the start of the string)
- `[\W\w]*` Matches no characters, as it needs to match the next part
- `\S$` Matches `a` at the end of the string